# jaxws-maven-plugin and proxy exclusions

Tags: maven, proxy, wsimport, http-proxy

I use jaxws-maven-plugin to produce java from wsdl.
wsdl located in local network, but refers to some xsd in internet.

It becomes troubles in generation code with maven plugin, becouse it has lack of advanced http proxy settings.

Is there a workaround for this issue?
My config is:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>wsimport</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
         <!--<httpproxy>127.0.0.1:5865</httpproxy>-->
            <packageName>my.pkg</packageName>
            <verbose>true</verbose>
            <wsdlUrls>
                <wsdlUrl>
                    http://10.31.7.64:13080/service.wsdl
                </wsdlUrl>
            </wsdlUrls>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Without proxy I got

```
parsing WSDL...

[ERROR] IOException thrown when processing "http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime". Exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect.
```

With proxy  I got

```
parsing WSDL...


[ERROR] Server returned HTTP response code: 504 for URL: http://10.31.7.64:13080/service.wsdl
```

May be it problem of proxy, but I don't have another proxy behind corporate network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIU, when we enable the `httpproxy`, all request will go to that proxy, including with the `<wsdlUrl>`.

The server returns

```
HTTP response code: 504 for URL: http://10.31.7.64:13080/service.wsdl
```

The [Status Code Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) told us as the following: -

> #### 504 Gateway Timeout
>
> The server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, did not receive a timely response from the upstream server specified by the URI (e.g. HTTP, FTP, LDAP) or some other auxiliary server (e.g. DNS) it needed to access in attempting to complete the request.

The root cause may be the proxy does not known our address, in this case it is `10.31.7.64`

IMHO please try to download the `wsdl` and put it to local machine. Then configured by using the [wsdlFiles](http://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/wsimport-mojo.html#wsdlFiles) as the following example: -

```xml
 <configuration>
     <wsdlFiles>
         <wsdlFile>${basedir}/path/to/wsdl</wsdlFile>
     </wsdlFiles>
 </configuration>
```

I hope this may help.

Answer (score 3):

A better approach is to use the noProxy variable of the JVM. Then your build fails when the WSDL is not available (In my case very useful for integration tests) You can add this to the `jaxws-maven-plugin` configuration:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.4.1</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>wsdltoJava</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>wsimport</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <wsdlUrls>
                <wsdlUrl>https://someService.yourcompany.net/Service/Service?wsdl</wsdlUrl>
            </wsdlUrls>
            <vmArgs>
                <vmArg>-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=*.yourcompany.net, 10.31.7.64</vmArg>
            </vmArgs>
            <keep>true</keep>
            <packageName>com.yourcompany.package</packageName>
            <sourceDestDir>your/target/directory</sourceDestDir>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```